# How do I add a vertical scrollbar to a centred, expanding table?

Tags: html, css

I have a rather long table, and I wish to add a vertical scrollbar to it. To do this, I've wrapped the table inside two divs. The inner div has `display: inline-block` so that it will shrink wrap around the table, and the outer div has `text-align: center`.

Here's the problem: I've  added `overflow-y: auto` to the inner div, and this apparently adds a scrollbar to the *inside* of the inner div, which makes the content wider equal to the width of the vertical scrollbar, which spawns a *horizontal* scrollbar.

I can't find a good solution to this. Ideally, the width of the inner wrapper div should expand to accomodate the vertical scrollbar, rather than spawning a horizontal scroll bar.

Any ideas?

<sub>I'm using Chrome 42 and Firefox 39 in this case.</sub>

---

Example demonstrating the issue:

```css
body {
  font: 14px "Verdana", "Arial", "Sans Serif";
}
#wrapper1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#wrapper2 {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 150px;
  
  text-align: initial;
}
table {
  min-width: 512px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
table td {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1">
  <div id="wrapper2">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Foo</th>
          <th>Bar</th>
          <th>Baz</th>
          <th>Foo</th>
          <th>Bar</th>
          <th>Baz</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I have also tried using `width: max-content` as well as `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block` to shrink wrap the div, and the horizontal scroll bar issue remains the same.

Note: Adding padding to the inner div equal to the width of the scroll bar (16px) hacks around the issue in my current browsers, but is obviously a terrible long term solution:

```css
body {
  font: 14px "Verdana", "Arial", "Sans Serif";
}
#wrapper1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#wrapper2 {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 150px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  
  text-align: initial;
}
table {
  min-width: 512px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
table td {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1">
  <div id="wrapper2">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Foo</th>
          <th>Bar</th>
          <th>Baz</th>
          <th>Foo</th>
          <th>Bar</th>
          <th>Baz</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try with `overflow:scroll` for the innerdiv.Am using lower version of chrome,could able to replicate the issue and using `overflow:scroll` its working perfect for me.

Comment: That does indeed work (for some reason), but the reason I have it set to `auto` is that I don't want scroll bars when the table is below an acceptable height.